# A closed cylindrical can is to be made so that its volume is $52cm^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A closed cylindrical can is to be made so that its volume is $52cm^3$. Find its dimensions such that the surface area is to be minimum.

My attempt 
Let $x$ be the radius $y$ be the height of the cylinder.  Then 
$$\textrm {Volume}=\pi x^2y$$
$$52=\pi x^2y$$
$$y=\dfrac {52}{\pi x^2}$$
Let $f(x)=\dfrac {52}{\pi x^2}$
$$f'(x)=-\dfrac {104}{x^2}$$
$f'(x)=0$ gives 
$$\dfrac {104}{x^2}=0$$

Comment: Where is the formula for surface area used here?Use the relation between $x$ and $y$  got from volume relation  to get surface area as a function of one variable and then minimize that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume is $$V=\pi r^2 h $$

the surface area is
$$S(r)=2\pi r^2+2\pi r h $$
$$=2\pi r^2 +2\pi r \frac {V}{\pi r^2} $$
$$=2\pi r^2+\frac {2V}{r} $$

$$S'(r)=4\pi r -\frac {2V}{r^2}=0$$

thus
$$r=(\frac {V}{2\pi})^\frac13$$